# vuejs la busqueda en data table en vuetify es muy lenta

Tags: datatables, vuetify

tengo un array con mas de 7,000 datos, cuando hago la búsqueda en un data table de vuetify, la escritura en el texfield es muy lenta, tarda unos segundos en colocar y buscar letra por letra.

```
<v-data-table
      :headers="header"
      :items="item"
      :search="search"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
```

hay alguna manera eficiente de resolver esto?

Answer (score 0):

**No es eficiente** ,traer 7 mil datos de un solo vuelco y mostrarlos en un data table ,en cualquier caso esto siempre sera lento de procesar , y peor  que tus datos vallan creciendo con el tiempo...

Lo que debes hacer es **Paginacion desde el Servidor**, así solo traerás los datos que el usuario necesita ver.

**Por ejemplo**, 
supongamos que estamos paginando de 10 en 10. En este caso, para obtener la tercera página (de la fila 21 a la 30), podríamos ejecutar una consulta como la siguiente.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.MiTabla
ORDER BY ID
OFFSET 20 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Para buscar puedes utilizar [Like](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017),

**Referencias:** http://www.guillesql.es/Articulos/Paginar_datos_SQLServer2012_OFFSET_FETCH.aspx
https://www.sqlshack.com/es/sql-server-2012-introduccion-paginacion/

**Utilizarlo con vuetify**

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/paginations#paginations